# Backslash and apostrophe not storing in MySQL using CodeIgniter properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Config file.

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Here is my string that I want to insert into the database.

```
$str ='Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur, France';
```

and I have converted this string into this using `add_slashes` function:

```
Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur, France
```

But in the database it keeps storing like this:

```
'Provence-Alpes-Côte d&#039;Azu';
```

This adds `&#039` instead of `\'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey there. Can you please post the code that adds this to the database? Also it seems that xss filtering is doing this to escape any potential issues as that kindof slashing is how people do injection. I personally don't use xss filtering, and I know *many* advise against it opting for better validation rather than filtering. You could also disable it globally and just use it when you think you need it (again I never use it).

Comment: @Alex,This is how i am inserting this record in db.
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`full_address`) VALUES ("Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur")

Comment: Global xss filtering *only* effects posts and cookies. If you are inserting it this way I can't see how it is getting converted to this. Is there anything you aren't telling us? Using query builder can you try this and tell me if its working, perhaps the protect identifiers feature is doing it, doing it this way might help: `$this->db->set('full_address', "Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur", false); $this->db->insert('test_table');`

Comment: @KhiradBanu if that's literally your code there's no way it could be causing this problem.

Comment: @ADyson,Actullay this is my code,When i copy this query and run in phpmyadmin its works fine,but when i try with codeignitor way,i got this "$#039" in the record

Comment: I doubt that's how you're literally writing the query in CodeIgniter, though. Can you show the actual PHP code which generates and executes this query?

Comment: @ADyson,Please have a look at this.
https://paste.laravel.io/aea22c6f-9c21-4d55-84ca-0721e3841a69

Comment: Please insert the relevant bits of your code into the question itself, thanks. Anyway all that code does is create a SQL string (which is probably vulnerable to SQL injection), it doesn't actually execute it. And are we to assume that `$_POST["address"]` contains `"Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur, France"` in that example?

Comment: In fact that code doesn't even work - $fields and $values are both undefined and $content never gets used. Please post some actual, real, working code which generates your query

Comment: @ADyson,I have updated the code,have a look at this one please.
https://paste.laravel.io/587b9ed4-6dff-41d0-8218-6005396f5cb9

Comment: **Please insert the relevant bits of your code into the question itself, thanks**. There is no need to use external links - 1) it's more effort for people to go and read your code, and 2) external links can change or die over time, making the question useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Anyway, it's still incomplete. For instance, what does your "clean" function do? And why aren't you using parameterised queries? This is a dreadful, error-prone, injection-vulnerable way to create SQL. I don't know Laravel, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't provide a proper, secure and reliable way to add parameter values to a query based on the underlying PHP/MySQL libraries

Comment: @ADyson,So i think it should use default active record for this,instead of this custom code

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "default active record" but you should certainly research how to create parameterised queries using Laravel's SQL API

Comment: @ADyson,Thank you for your time,much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the query builder method I posted?

Comment: You can set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` and your problem will probably go away.

Comment: @Alex: i tried that way too,still problem persists.

Comment: @BrianGottier, I have set this to False,but still same problem

Comment: your clean() function is probably to blame

Comment: @KhiradBanu, you need to debug that string. Set up some logging at various points, and see when the string is altered.

Comment: @BrianGottier: when i echo last query,it has backslash,and when i copy that query and paste in phpmyadmin,works fine,but when i run this query with CI,it adds that string

Comment: @Alex: i have removed that function,just adding the stuff like you advised earlier.

Comment: What CI version are you running? And not that it would affect anything, but did you try setting xss_filtering to false - what was the outcome? Unfortunately I cannot replicate your issue: https://imgur.com/a/xXd7d

Comment: @Alex,i fixed as you did in the example.Thank you very much.
Can you please post this answer as well,so other may take help from this.

Comment: Again it doesn't make sense. Codeigniter won't do it. I've proven that with my imgur. Xss filtering did you disable it0

Comment: @Alex,you are right.

Comment: Solved? What was the issue then? Xss filtering post vars?

Comment: @Alex,yes xss_clean was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable xss_filtering:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

xss filtering is doing this to escape any potential issues as that kindof slashing is how people do injection.

Generally even CodeIgniter devs say to avoid it:

> The ‘global_xss_filtering’ setting is DEPRECATED and kept solely for
>   backwards-compatibility purposes. XSS escaping should be performed on
>   output, not input!

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html